# System.InvalidOperationException:'Connection Property must not be null' in MySQL Connection

Tags: c#, mysql, xamarin.forms

While Testing the project I came across the error ***"System.InvalidOperationException:'Connection property must be non-null***.
Attempting to fix the error, I edited database values and re-defined enter_email and the Email Entry. Looking online to find the cause of the problem, I found the page for this error, however, no reference to my message or the cause of it was found. I placed the server info into a separate variable. I'm unsure of the cause of this error. Could anyone explain it to me?

The code giving the error is here:

```
async void LoginClick(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        var Server = "server=myip;user=app;database=travel_logger;port=3306;password=app; default command timeout=20;";
        string enter_email = Email.Text;
        using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(Server))
        {
            connection.Open();
            var cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT _Password FROM * WHERE email=" + enter_email);
            var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
            string data_password = reader.GetString(0);
            if (data_password == Password.Text)
            {
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new AboutPage());
            }
            else
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Login Error", "Incorrect email or password","Okay");
            }
            connection.Close();
        }; 
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you resolve the error from your previous question?  In the code you posted here, you are not linking the command to the connection

Comment: @Jason The previous post was resolved and could you explain the cause of the error in a little more detail. Thanks

Comment: See the answer another user posted.  It would be helpful if you posted an answer to the previous question so anyone with a similar problem can refer to it in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's throw error because your command doesn't know which connection your command use. You need to pass your connection to your `MySqlCommand` when initialize.

```
var cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT _Password FROM * WHERE email=" + enter_email);
cmd.Connection = connection; // <- add this row
```